# Online product/photos management software with tagging

Tags: file-management, product-management, catalog

Long story short, I have spent some time looking for a management/cataloging software but it feels like I'm looking at wrong categories. I had a look at different PIM (Product Information Management) platforms, but they are all target corporate users and are usually quite sophisticated in features.

So, I collect physical items which I'd like to manage. By manage, I mean I'd like to see a list of them, sort them by some metadata, filtering, categorising. I need to be able to upload multiple photos of each item.

It needs to be online and free. I don't need them to host the actual images for me, I can upload them anywhere (S3, Google Drive, Google Photos, etc.). I can fill in metadata manually or an import feature of some prepared csv file would be an extra benefit.

I need a web interface so that it's as cross-platform as possible. An extra benefit would be to be able to share a URL so that someone can view my items, filtered.

I'd do with Google Photos and Albums if only it supported filtering and tagging.

I noticed plenty of shop engines do offer that.

What names should I look at? Is what I described a PIM software? Any product you recommend checking before I start rolling it as my pet project?

Thanks a lot!